# Can't get local box VM running using Vagrant on Windows 7 - bad URI error

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I get stuck when I'm trying to run the `vagrant up` command. I have this local .box file sitting in my local drive and fist ran `vagrant init`, and then added it. Adding seemed to go fine, but when I tried running `vagrant up` as shown below, it returns:

**C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): file:C:/Users/burea1124/Projects/theirgoods/CUserurea1124Projectstheirgoodstheirgoods_dev_vm.box (URI::InvalidURIError)**

Obviously it looks like I'm supposed to fix the URI somewhere but I have no idea why it looks like that in the first place. Does anybody have any clues to how I can fix this?

> C:\Users\burea1124\Projects\theirgoods>vagrant box add theirgoods
>   C:\Users\burea1124\Projects\theirgoods\theirgoods_dev_vm.box
>   ==> box: Adding box 'theirgoods' (v0) for provider:
>       box: Downloading: file://C:/Users/burea1124/Projects/theirgoods/theirgoods_dev_vm.box
>       box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 500M/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
>   ==> box: Successfully added box 'theirgoods' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
>
> C:\Users\burea1124\Projects\theirgoods> vagrant up 
>   Bringing
>   machine'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   ==> default: Box 'CUserurea1124Projectstheirgoodstheirgoods_dev_vm.box' could not be
>   found. Attempting to find and install...
>       default: Box Provider: virtualbox
>       default: Box Version: >= 0 C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in
>   `split': bad URI(is not URI?):
>   file:C:/Users/burea1124/Projects/theirgoods/CUserurea1124Projectstheirgoodstheirgoods_dev_vm.box
>   (URI::InvalidURIError)
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:211:in`
>   parse'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in
>   `parse'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:458:in`
>   metadata_url?'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:77:in
>   `block in call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:75:in`
>   map'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:75:in
>   `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`
>   call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in
>   `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in`
>   block in run'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in
>   `busy'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in`
>   run'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:79:in
>   `handle_box'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:42:in`
>   block in call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:36:in
>   `synchronize'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:36:in`
>   call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in
>   `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in`
>   block in finalize_action'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in
>   `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`
>   call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in
>   `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in`
>   block in run'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in
>   `busy'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in`
>   run'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in
>   `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`
>   call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in
>   `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`
>   call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in
>   `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in`
>   block in run'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in
>   `busy'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in`
>   run'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:196:in
>   `action_raw'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:173:in`
>   block in action'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:434:in
>   `lock'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in`
>   call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in
>   `action'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in`
>   block (2 levels) in run'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in your `Vagrantfile` you're referencing the box with the full path, you have to use the box name instead:

```
config.vm.box = "theirgoods"
```

Answer (score 2):

This was the top question when I searched for that error. The problem in my case was that I added the box correctly, but I copied over an existing Vagrantfile and forgot to do `vagrant init`.

So for anyone else with this error, make sure you are doing `vagrant init` :)